# Is it possible to have hypothermia without shivering?

Tags: hypothermia

If a person is cold and has severe vertigo (dizziness is a known affect of hypothermia I think) can the cause of hypothermia be ruled out simply because the person is not shivering?  What factors could make a hypothermic person not shiver, as this is usually the essential symptom?

Comment: Welcome to MedSci.  The short answer is yes, you can be hypothermic without shivering. Not shivering is  actually a distinctive sign of severe hypothermia, so your assumption that it's an essential symptom is off base.

Comment: For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post.  I am not a medic by trade, but of course I did research and discovered that dizziness is possible for hypothermia but everything I found suggested shivering was the decisive symptom.  I sincerely apologize for my ignorance.  Are you an expert on hypothermia?

Comment: No, I'm not an expert on hypothermia and don't need to be, and neither do you. Yes, shivering is one of the early signs of hypothermia, but you need to dig deeper. Suggest you google 'paradoxical undressing'.